# Simple regex help in coldfusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I have a string that I wish to remove some characters based on underscores in the string. For instance.

I wish to change

```
2_MASTER BEDROOM_CFM
```

to

```
MASTER BEDROOM
```

OR

```
2734923ie_BEDROOM 2_CFM
```

to

```
BEDROOM 2
```

Any recomendations on how to do this with coldfusion?

Comment: You could use GetToken()

Comment: Just to expand on Matt's comment, he is suggesting you treat the string as a list delimited by underscores ie `_`. Then simply use list functions to grab the second element, instead of a regular expression.  See [getToken()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6e22.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ColdFusion has the `GetToken()` function, which makes manipulating a string with a delimiter (virtually any delimiter) very easy. Assuming each string you're looking to parse is 2 sets of strings then this will output `MASTER BEDROOM`

```
<cfset String1 = '2_MASTER BEDROOM_CFM'>
<cfset FirstWord = ListFirst(String1,' ')>
<cfset FirstWord = GetToken(FirstWord,2,'_')>
<cfset SecondWord = ListLast(String1,' ')>
<cfset SecondWord = GetToken(SecondWord,1,'_')>

<cfoutput>
  #FirstWord# #SecondWord#
</cfoutput>
```

Could also simplify it down to just

```
<cfset String1 = '2_MASTER BEDROOM_CFM'>
<cfoutput>
  #GetToken(ListFirst(String1,' '),2,'_')# #GetToken(ListLast(String1,' '),1,'_')#
</cfoutput>
```

EDIT As Leigh points out in the comments you could also just use

```
getToken("2_MASTER BEDROOM_CFM", 2, "_")
```

This treats your string as a list with elements `2`, `MASTER BEDROOM`, and `CFM`

Comment: I could be wrong, but my take was they just wanted the second list element (with spaces). If so a simple `getToken("2_MASTER BEDROOM_CFM", 2, "_")` should do it.

Comment: @Leigh Good point, I think the space threw off my thinking. I added your comment into my answer.

Comment: Thanks guys! I am new to regex and knew there were some pretty easy answers to this.

Answer (score 0):

So the string starts with some numbers and/or characters, then an underscore.  Then some text, finally an underscore followed by CFM?  Here's a regex that catches that:

```
^[a-z0-9]+_(.*)_CFM$
```

And here's some code that works for me:

```
<cfoutput>
<cfset String1 = '2_MASTER BEDROOM_CFM'>
<cfset yourString = reReplaceNoCase(String1, "^[a-z0-9]+_(.*)_CFM$", "\1")>

#yourString#<br>

<cfset String2 = "2734923ie_BEDROOM 2_CFM">
<cfset yourString = reReplaceNoCase(String2, "^[a-z0-9]+_(.*)_CFM$", "\1")>

#yourString#<br>
</cfoutput>
```